# How to write unit test/ mini test for a class which has self.method with few hardcoded class in that method( I am new at writing tests in ror)?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

I have given a task to write unit test in rails for this particular class which was written back in 2017, but since i am new to this and the code stucture is so bad that i am not able to find best way to write unit test for it, can anyone please help with this or give some insight.

Also i have been told to not change the business logic much for it.

```
module Alpha
  module Beta
    module Gamma
      class User
        class SsoUser
          def self.find(type, organization, user_identifier)
            if user_identifier.blank?
              raise Error.new(
                'user_identifier must be provided',
                400,
                'missing.required.attribute'
              )
            end

            case type.try(:downcase)
            when 'admin'
              AdminUser.new().find_admin(organization, user_identifier)
            when 'subscriber'
              SubscriberUser.find(organization, user_identifier)
            when 'master_admin'
              AdminUser.new().find_master_admin(organization,user_identifier)
            else
              raise Error.new(
                "'type' parameter must be one of [admin,subscriber,master_admin]",
                400,
                'missing.required.attribute'
              )
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now the class name for which i need to write test is SsoUser and the other classes used here are Error, AdminUser(returns user object based on type-'admin' or type-'master_admin'), SubscriberUser(also returns user based on type-'subscriber').

user_identifier is the 'user_name' which is string, type is also string as mentioned, organiaztion will give an id.

Sorry in advance if anything left vague.

I am having problem writing tests for self.method in this class.
Also how to test for those hard coded class which should ideally be written in constructor method.
I didn’t tried much because i am still new to this.

Answer (score 0):

I can show you where to start and using the same principle continue with your test

```rb
require "test_helper"

class Alpha::Beta::Gamma::User::SsoUserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "arise with Error" do
   err = -> { Alpha::Beta::Gamma::User::SsoUser.find(nil, nil, nil)}.must_raise Error
   err.message.must_match /user_identifier must be provided/
  end

  test "find Admin" do
   assert_instance_of AdminUser, Alpha::Beta::Gamma::User::SsoUser.find('admin', organization(:first), user(:admin).user_identifier)
  end
end
```

organization(:first) and user(:admin) - this are fixtures that you should create in your test folder (/test/fixtures/user.yml and /test/fixtures/organization.yml) On this [page](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Fixtures.html) you can find more details about using fixtures.
On this [page](https://devhints.io/minitest) you can find additional assertions and tools that can help you with writing tests

I wrote approximate code which can contain potential errors, but the general idea looks like that